# Insert array property in DGV (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, class, datagridview, properties

I wrote a class called `Section` which has 2 properties: `Answers` and `TypeOfSection`.
So, `TypeOfSection` shows perfectly in the DGV, But I want to show the value for each cell inside the array, how could I achieve that?

```
class Section
{
    private int[] Answers;
    private string TypeOfSection;

    public Section(string TypeOfSection)
    {
        Answers = new int[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            this.Answers[i] = -1;
        }
        this.TypeOfSection = TypeOfSection;
    }

    public string typeOfSection
    {
        set { this.TypeOfSection = value; }
        get { return this.TypeOfSection; }
    }

    public int[] answers
    {
        set { this.Answers = value; }
        get { return this.Answers; }
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
    List<Section> Psy1 = new List<Section>();
    Psy1.Add(new Section("English"));
    MarksDGV1.DataSource = Psy1;
```

Comment: Rather than use a class I like using a DataTable as the source of the DGV.  Using DataTable the mapping is done much better than using classes.

Comment: The issue may be coming from the `Section` class. The `Section` class has two properties, a `string` `TypeOfSection` and a “collection” of `ints` in an array. When you use this class in a `List<Section>`, as a `DataSource` to a `DataGridView`, the `TypeOfSection` will display properly, however the `Answers` column will be missing because it is a “collection.” Each instance of the `Section` class… in the `List` is a “row” in the grid. That is why any “collection” properties in a class will not be mapped to a column, since each cell in that column would have to have “multiple” items in it.

Comment: If you really want to put all the `ints` from the array into “one” cell, then I recommend the `Section` class implement a `public` `property` (not a method) that returns the `ints` in a `string`. This “property” should then be properly mapped as a column into the grid with all the numbers in the array in each cell.

Comment: Just as JohnG stated, your code is attempting to map a list of int arrays to individual cells of a DGV column - it will not inherently know how to display this information. It may be useful if you could include an example mock-up in your question of *how you want your data to be displayed*.